# Chain-Inheritance with the Building-Pattern

Tags: java

i have a problem to get this pattern right with the java generics or maybe it wont work at all. Id like to have 2 abstract classes and a normal one. 
Each childclass brings his own parameters to the classes. Form my perspective it looks like, i messed up with the generics, but i have no clue where.

```
public abstract class First {

private final long id;

First(Builder<?> builder) {
    this.id = builder.getId();
}


public static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

    @Getter long id;

    public abstract First build();

    public T setID(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return (T)self();
    }

    protected abstract T self();
}
```

second:

```
public abstract class Second extends First {

Second(Builder<?> builder) { 
    super(builder);
}


public static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends First.Builder {

    public T print() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return (T) self();
    }

}
}
```

and third:

```
public class Third extends Second {

private Third(Builder builder) {
    super(builder);
}

public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Second.Builder {

    public Third build() {

        return new Third(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected Builder self() {
        return this;
    }
}

}
```

my problem is, that i can call:

```
new Third.Builder()
            .print()
            .setID(1)
            .build();
```

but not:

```
new Third.Builder()
            .setID(1)
            .print()
            .build();
```

java gives me:

```
Error:(13, 17) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method print()
location: class blub.First.Builder
```

Comment: Use Lombok's [`@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) and save yourself the bother

Comment: i will check it out